# Checking for palindromes

Tags: list-comprehension

```
    def palindrome(s):
        for i in range(0,len(s)-1):
            if s[i] == s[i][::-1]:
                return s[i]
words = ['foof','boom','aanaa','nana']
print(palindrome(words))
```

am trying to make it check for palindromes in a huge text, though, beside the point, I only found one palindrome with my function. I decided to test it with something trivial, but it only regards 'foof' as a palindrome. There is something fundamentally wrong with the for loop, my guess, but I cannot, for the world of me, figure out what the problem is.

A side question: my first post I wrote the code and used the Code Sample button to make it format as a code, somewhat, but somebody had to edit my post so there would be these syntax colours in the code. How can I do it myself, so there would be no need for someone else to edit my posts? :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your return statement, the function will stop executing as soon as it finds the first palindrome.

You need to create a new list inside your function and each palindrome to that.

```
def palindrome(s):
    l = []
    for i in range(0,len(s)-1):
        if s[i] == s[i][::-1]:
            l.append(s[i])
    return l
```

The function should return a list of palindromes and not just the first one...

Comment: many thanks to you. I had thought a for loop would continue based on the number of iterations it is set to go through.